# JBOSS EAP5.2 Clustering

Tags: jboss, cluster-computing

I am using JBOSS EAP5.2 cluster behind apache using mod_cluster. Complete scenario is below:

- 04 Jboss instances. 02 instance on each physical server
- 02 Apache Web Server having mod_cluster configured.

I received an alert from automation system that website is down. I checked and it was really down. I checked the servers and they all seem healthy. I go through the server.log and saw following lines.

2015-02-21 04:26:05,475 WARN  [NAKACK] 192.168.3.10:55200] discarded message from non-member 192.168.3.14:55200, my view is [192.168.3.2:55200|04] [192.168.3.2:55200, 192.168.3.10:55200]

I killed the java process running on 192.168.3.14 jboss server and website started to respond normally. I started back the instances and the behavior is normal now.

Can anyone help me on how to find out what happened and even if one cluster member was stuck, why does it cause the whole website down.

Comment: Take a look in https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/TwoClustersOnTheSameNetwork

Comment: My worry is that whole cluster just stopped responding by the time one member was out due to some error like it may be receiving traffic from user but not serving back. The other nodes must keep responding which does not happen in this case. which is best place to look inside JBOOS now, either configuration whole cluster design.